# Iterating via given array or range of this array when nested for-loop takes place

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am new to python so far and have encountered  while trying to loop via nested for loop in for loop:

```
def find_it(seq):     
        count = 0      
        for i in seq:
              for j in seq:
                  if seq[i] == seq[j]:
                        count = count + 1                       
              if count % 2 != 0:
                   return seq[i]

find_it([20, 20, 1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5])
```

And here I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(find_it([20, 20, 1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]))
  File "test.py", line 7, in find_it
    if seq[i] == seq[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But then I tried just use range(0, n - 1):

```
def find_it(seq):     
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(seq)):
              for j in range(0, len(seq)):
                  if seq[i] == seq[j]:
                        count = count + 1              
              if count % 2 != 0:
                   return seq[i]

print(find_it([20, 20, 1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5]))
```

And there is no exception occurred then.
Can you help please with what part of the essence I didn't get at all?

Comment: range(0, n) in the third piece of code. I missed that part.

Comment: `for i in seq:` and `seq[i]` is not correct. Simply use `i` instead of `seq[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the elements of the list. In place of `seq[i]` and `seq[j]`, try writing `i` and `j`.

Hope this helps.